# How to get the Last Published Date of the page?

Tags: dxa, dxa-1.2

I need to get the Last Published Date of the Page in Tridion DXA 1.2

When I preview the page in CME, I am seeing an attribute in JSON ouput as below

> "LastPublishedDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"

Value of the attribute is always as above, it is not giving the right value ever and it is not added to the DXA Page Model at delivery side to use it.

So, decided to get the `LastpublishedDate` from Broker Data Base, **Items** table.

Is there any DXA OOTB method to get the LastPublishedDate from Broker DB?

Comment: I'm not surprised it gives you that on preview... have you checked what it contains once it's published? Otherwise, this is available in the page metadata

Comment: Once it is published, am not seeing that attribute in my page model. However, I am able to see other details like page revision date in my page model.

Comment: @Hiren: am using DXA not DD4T in my delivery. I could not use `PageMetaFactory` because of `internal class PublicationResolver : IPublicationResolver` in `Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping` namespace.

Comment: As nuno highlighted you can get it from page metadata, this was dd4t way however similar thing should be possible for DXA.

Comment: Please clarify why you can not use `PageMetaFactory`.

Comment: @Rick: I need to call `GetLastPublishedDateByUri`  via `DD4T.Providers.SDLTridion2013sp1 TridionPageProvider` class. this class implements `IProvidersCommonServices` which has one of the internal class `PublicationResolver`. This is the reason, am not able to using this. I read, I can invoke internal class using Reflection. But not sure can pass as parameter to the `IProvidersCommonServices` interface. But trying to check any other easy way to get the last published date from DXA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It indeed seems that `Page.LastPublishedDate` is never set by DD4T Templates. DXA (currently) also has no OOTB model mapping for this property.

However, it is quite easy to obtain the last publish date using the CD API. Something like:

```
PageMetaFactory pageMetaFactory = new PageMetaFactory(Convert.ToInt32(localization.LocalizationId));
IPageMeta pageMeta =  pageMetaFactory.GetMeta(Convert.ToInt32(pageModel.Id));
DateTime lastPublishDate = pageMeta.LastPublicationDate;
```

There is no need to use the DD4T Provider for this purpose.

If you want all your Page Models to have a last publish date set, you could create your own Page Controller: a subclass of DXA's built-in `PageController` which overrides the `EnrichModel` method. You can put above logic in that override. You could store the date in `PageModel.ExtensionData`:

```
using Sdl.Web.Mvc.Controllers;
using System;
using Sdl.Web.Common.Models;

namespace Example
{
    public class MyPageController : PageController
    {
        protected override ViewModel EnrichModel(ViewModel model)
        {
            PageModel pageModel = (PageModel) base.EnrichModel(model);

            Localization localization = WebRequestContext.Localization;
            PageMetaFactory pageMetaFactory = new PageMetaFactory(Convert.ToInt32(localization.LocalizationId));
            IPageMeta pageMeta = pageMetaFactory.GetMeta(Convert.ToInt32(pageModel.Id));
            pageModel.SetExtensionData("LastPublishDate", pageMeta.LastPublicationDate);

            return pageModel;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW: DXA does include the last publish date of Pages in the Navigation Model (try opening `/Navigation.json`)

Comment: Thanks Rick, it works. Am able to get the published date from Tridion CD.