# DXA Custom controller for PageModel

Tags: dxa, dxa-net

I want to handle PageModel using custom Controller/Action in DXA module.

I added controller:

```
public class CustomPageController : PageController
{
    public override ActionResult Page(string pageUrl)
    {
        return base.Page(pageUrl);
    }
}
```

and registered page model view:

```
RegisterViewModel("AssetPage", typeof(PageModel), "CustomPage");
```

but when I'm triyng to reach the page I get the error: No View Model registered for View 'MyWeb:Page:AssetPage'. Check that you have registered this View in the 'MyWeb' area registration.

Comment: You probably want to do something with the Page Model in your custom Page Controller. In that case, you should override `EnrichModel` instead of `Page`.

Comment: See, for example: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/15672/how-to-get-the-last-published-date-of-the-page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Page Controller is resolved through MVC Routing rather than through DXA View Model Registration.

In order to use a custom Page Controller, you should change the "Tridion Page Route" in `RegisterRoutes` in `Global.asax.cs`. https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet/blob/master/Site/Global.asax.cs

Don't specify the third parameter in `RegisterViewModel` (that is intended for custom Entity Controllers).

Comment: HI @Rick, 
We have tried adding custom controller by extending PageController of Sdl.Web.Mvc project, also added new { controller = "MyPage", action = "Page" } under "Tridion Route Page", also override method Page under MyController, but debug point is not triggering on MyPageController, Please advise on this what should be the problem?