# DXA JAVA Custom controller for PageModel

Tags: dxa, dxa-java

I want to customize the page controller in a DXA JAVA implementation. Is that possible, and how?

I tried to extend the DXA PageController, but of course [that does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29751416/how-to-override-requestmapping-in-another-controller)

```
@Controller
public class MyPageController extends PageController {

    @RequestMapping(
            value = {"/jan"},
            params = {"test"},
            produces = {"text/html", "*/*"}
    )
    @Override
    public String handleGetPage(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        // do your stuff
        return super.handleGetPage(request, response);
    }
}
```

The problem is that in Spring there is no way to override the `@RequestMapping`, and each mapping has to be unique.

@bearddev had a [similar question](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/15692/dxa-custom-controller-for-pagemodel) for DXA .NET. The .NET answer does not apply to DXA JAVA as routing is not configured in a single place in DXA JAVA.

The [DXA documentation mentions](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v7/GUID-B90B888E-7A84-4BB7-8832-8563C26C2646) how to *"Create a controller class"*, but that only applies to region and entity controllers.

Answer (score 6):

The solution is surprisingly simple.

```
@Controller
public class MyPageController {

    @Autowired
    private PageController pageController;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/articles")
    public String handleGetPage(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        return pageController.handleGetPage(request, response);
    }
}
```

You only need to inject the controller you want to customize, define specifix mappings (`PageController` has least specific mapping `/**` and thus gets least priority) and delegate execution to original class if needed or define your own logic.

Comment: Thanks @Alexey!  I would like my page controller to catch all page requests, as in `@RequestMapping(value = "/**")`. Is this possible at all given that the DXA controller already registered that route?

Comment: I found a variant on your solution, with a catchall `RequestMapping` which has a more specific mapping than the catchall mapping from the DXA Page Contorller. It is posted as a separate answer.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to [@Alexey's answer](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/18252/88) which pushed me in the right direction.

This `MyPageController` controller does the trick. Just like the DXA `PageController` it is very greedy, that means it wants to match all requests. See [code](https://gist.github.com/jhorsman/c14c076fd2a5bb27ba73be78c77ad2eb) and explanation below.

```
@Controller
public class MyPageController {

    // Inject the PageController, because we cannot override and change the RequestMapping
    @Autowired
    private PageController pageController;

    // This mapping is more specific than the DXA PageController mapping
    @RequestMapping(
            value = {"/**"},
            produces = {"text/html", "*/*"},
            method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST}
    )
    public String handleGetPage(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        String view = pageController.handleGetPage(request, response);

        PageModel pageModel = (PageModel) request.getAttribute("pageModel");
        pageModel = this.enrichModel(pageModel, request);
        request.setAttribute("pageModel", pageModel);

        return view;
    }

    // enrich the page model, with the DXA enrichModel() pattern 
    protected PageModel enrichModel(PageModel pageModel, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) throws Exception {

        //do your thing here
        pageModel.setTitle("Hello, World!");

        return pageModel;
    }
}
```

Indeed the `@RequestMapping` cannot be overridden, but like Alexey shows that is not needed.

The `RequestMapping` (route) needs to be unique which is a challenge, since the DXA `PageController` registers a greedy catchall route. By adding the request `method` to the `RequestMapping`, the `MyPageController` mapping is more specific than the DXA `PageController` one.

From the DXA `PageController`

```
@RequestMapping(
    value = {"/**"},
    produces = {"text/html", "*/*"}
)
public String handleGetPage(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
```

From `MyPageController`

```
@RequestMapping(
        value = {"/**"},
        produces = {"text/html", "*/*"},
        method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST}
)
public String handleGetPage(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
```