# How to get the Last Published Date of the component

Tags: dxa, dd4t

We have requirement to get the Last Published Date of Component in tridion DXA 1.2

Is there any DXA OOTB method to get the LastPublishedDate from Broker DB?

Comment: What are you asking?

I see you updated your answer to remove getting the published date from a page - can you update so it contains the right information too? Are you using DCPs *and* static CPs?

Comment: Have you see this? http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/15672/how-to-get-the-last-published-date-of-the-page

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you not to get information directly from the Items table of the Content Delivery database. It is not supported and the database structure may be changed at any time (e.g. with a hotfix or version update). There is a supported API for retrieving Content Delivery data and metadata.

To find the last publication date of a page, obtain it's system metadata using the PageMetaFactory class. There is also a ComponentMetaFactory class which can give you the system metadata for components, including the last publication date, but I don't remember whether this is applicable to all components or only those which have been published using a dynamic component template.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a supported solution to get data directly from the database - you would be best advised using the supported APIs.

Have you tried anything in the API such as

```
PageProvider.GetLastPublishedDateByUri(page.Id)
```

or the solution presented on [TREX already](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/15672/how-to-get-the-last-published-date-of-the-page)?

Are you using DCPs? Read around/test when the publish date is updated - e.g. when published as a DCP and/or as a static CP on a page.